# Validation to check no existing overlaps with previous bookings

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to validate that a booking doesn't overlap in date and time with an
existing booking and return and error if a booking is overlapping an existing booking.

This is the code I have right now but it isn't working, and when I make another booking that overlaps an existing booking, it is still passing through and not returning an error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
id integer not null primary key autoincrement
created_at datetime, 
updated_at datetime,
carid integer,
sdate date not null,
edate date not null,
stime time not null,
etime time not null,
userid integer,
 foreign key("carid") references "cars"("id") on delete cascade, foreign key("userid") 
    references "users"("id") on delete cascade
);



$temp=DB::table('books')->where('sdate','>=',$sdate)->where('edate', '<=',$edate)->where('stime', '>=',$stime) ->where('etime','<=',$etime)->get();
if($temp) {
    $errorMsg="This overlaps with an existing booking, please choose another time.";
    $code='1';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$errorMsg.'");</script>';
}
else {
    //ok
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What are the datatypes of those columns in your DB and what are the values in your variables? Please show us some real data so we can see what's actually going on. Btw, why not keep the date and the time together in a datetime field instead of separating them into different columns?

Comment: Thanks, I added data in for you to see what's going on

Comment: Please read my comment again and respond to _all_ questions/requests for information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
$temp=DB::table('books')
->where(function($query)use($sdate,$edate){
     $query->whereBetween('sdate', [$sdate,$edate])
    ->orWhereBetween('edate', [$sdate,$edate]);
 })->where('stime','>=',$stime)->orWhere('etime','<=',$etime)->count();
if($temp > 0){
....
}else{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
if (count($temp) > 0) {
    $errorMsg="This overlaps with an existing booking, please choose another time.";
    $code='1';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$errorMsg.'");</script>';
} else {
    //ok
}
```

Comment: @a_puddycat If you **dd($temp)** with an existing record, what is the output ? Maybe your variable is still **null**, that's why the error is not displayed